# Issue while reading a parquet file with different data types like decimal using Dask read parquet

Tags: python, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I have some parquet files which are created by Spark converting AVRO file to parquet file. And these parquet files contain different data types like decimal, int,string,boolean. But when I read this file using the dd.read_parquet with pyarrow engine, except int everything else is converted to object data types and which causes an issue in arithmetic calculations. And i tried with the float dtypes for the decimal columns but that will loose precision. Any idea how to read the values withot loosing the precision ?

Schema for the parquet file

```
<pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at >
  created_by: parquet-mr version 1.10.1 (build a89df8f9932b6ef6633d06069e50c9b7970bebd1)
  num_columns: 7
  num_rows: 1
  num_row_groups: 1
  format_version: 1.0
  serialized_size: 4376 
ID: string
CODE: string
CURRENCY: string
DEDUCT: decimal(20, 2)
PERCENT: decimal(11, 10)
MIN_DEDUCT: decimal(20, 2)
MAX_DEDUCT: decimal(20, 2)
```

metadata

```
{b'org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata': b'{"type":"struct","fields":[{'
                                           b'"name":"ID","'
                                           b'type":"string","nullable":tr'
                                           b'ue,"metadata":{}},{"name":"'
                                           b'CODE","typ'
                                           b'e":"string","nullable":true,'
                                           b'"metadata":{}},{"name":"'
                                           b'CURRENCY","typ'
                                           b'e":"string","nullable":true,'
                                           b'"metadata":{}},{"name":"DEDU'
                                           b'CT","type":"decimal(20,2'
                                           b')","nullable":true,"metadata'
                                           b'":{}},{"name":"'
                                           b'DEDUCT","'
                                           b'type":"decimal(11,10)","null'
                                           b'able":true,"metadata":{}},{"'
                                           b'name":"MIN_DEDUCT","'
                                           b'type":"decimal(20,2)","nulla'
                                           b'ble":true,"metadata":{}},{"n'
                                           b'ame":"MAX_DEDUCT","t'
                                           b'ype":"decimal(20,2)","nullab'
                                           b'le":true,"metadata":{}}]}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will lose an precision by using floating-point (double, 64-bit) for the two-decimal-place columns, although you *will* get slightly different values.

For column PERCENT, you should still be perfectly safe, although it's less obvious. I expect this is an estimate anyway.

Although python does have a decimal type, which is capable of computations, arrow does not represent this (and neither does numpy), except as inefficient python objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are right for small decimal (like 2 decimal places) and less than 1 million the float is perfect solution. But actually my data contain more than 6 decimal places and values more than 1000000, so when ever I converted the data above 1 million it will automatically consider as exponential value, so there as well I lose precision.

Comment: Sorry, then you are out of luck. Loading percent columns into a pandas percent extension type could be implemented pretty easily, but it doesn't exist yet (afaik)

Comment: Thanks mate, still trying out something for a solution, do you know how the exact lose of precision while converting an object into a float64 type?

Comment: That will depend on the data itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format claims 15-17 decimal places.

Comment: one thing I noticed when I ran the same code with pandas dataframe it worked perfectly means the decimal columns are consider as object but still can do the arithmetic operations, but when it comes to Dask dataframe, the same decimal object is consider as string  and getting the error like TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"), any clue on this, or any work around ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head - perhaps report this as a bug to dask.

Comment: Thanks mate, will create a bug in dask

Comment: i created an issue in dask , and got a comment , to try with the latest version of dask and pyarrow, currently am using dask 2.3 and pyarrow 14.1, will update both and try again, so just for a clarification , do you know whether the latest version of dask support decimals dtypes? as you said pyarrow doesnt allow decimal as well it created as string object while reading the file using pq.read_table.

Comment: I am not aware of any change, but that is not authoritative...

Comment: Thanks mate, i am sort of stuck at the moment, our program runs completely in dask, and we are not aware of this decimal datatype issue at the begining, so as you said like we have only option to convert the decimal types columns to float64 right?.i am still wondering why the pandas can handle this decimal types columns, but even though the dask dataframe is a parallel and composed of the different smaller pandas dataframes and it couldn't handle the decimal..